# Zero sets intersect in a line

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

A line in $\mathbb{P}^3$ through points $[u_1:u_2:u_3:u_4]$ and $[v_1:v_2:v_3:v_4]$ is $\{[ku_1+lv_1:\dots:ku_3+lv_3]\}$ where either $k\ne 0$ or $l\ne 0$. But there's something worrying me, and it comes from the following problem.

Let $Z_1=Z(X_1^2-X_0X_2)$, $Z_2=Z(X_1X_2-X_0X_3)$, $Z_3=Z(X_2^2-X_1X_3)$. I want to show that $Z_1$ intersects $Z_2$ in the union of $Z_1\cap Z_2 \cap Z_3$ and a line in $\mathbb{P}^3(\mathbb{C})$.

I consider 3 cases: take $[X_0:X_1:X_2:X_3]\in Z_1\cap Z_2$

- if $X_1\ne 0$, then $X_0,X_2,X_3\ne 0$ and therefore $X_0=X_1X_2/X_3\implies X_3X_1^2=X_1X_2^2\implies X_3X_1=X_2^2$, so $[X_0:X_1:X_2:X_3]\in Z_1\cap Z_2 \cap Z_3$
- if $X_1=X_2=0$, then clearly $[X_0:X_1:X_2:X_3]\in Z_1\cap Z_2 \cap Z_3$
- if $X_1=0, X_2\ne 0$, then $X_0=0$ and I want to conclude that $[X_0:X_1:X_2:X_3]$ belongs to the line $\{[0:0:X_2:X_3]\}$

But in the latter case $X_3$ may be zero or nonzero. If it is nonzero, then by what I said at the beginning, $\{[0:0:X_2:X_3]\}$ is the line thorugh the points $[0:0:1:0]$ and $[0:0:0:1]$. However if $X_3$ is zero then $\{[0:0:X_2:X_3]\}=\{[0:0:X_2:0]\}$, and this is not a line because $[0:0:0:0]$ is not a point of $\mathbb{P}^3$.

So I have 2 questions:

1. What should I do with the case $X_3=0$?
2. Is the rest of my reasoning correct?

Comment: The third bullet, why does $X_1 = 0,X_2\neq 0$ imply that $X_0 = 0$?

Comment: @TannerStrunk: thanks, there was a typo in the definition of $Z_1$.

Comment: If $X_0=X_1=X_3=0$ you have just a point (which is indeed on the line passing through $[0:0:1:0]$ and $[0:0:0:1]$).

Comment: Your reasoning was correct except that you were treating the third case as kinda...separate from the case of $[X_0:X_1:X_2:X_3]\in Z_1\cap Z_2\cap Z_3$, and...it kinda is. But then you have to throw in a point at infinity to get a line.

Comment: You can think of like...decomposing the union of the two axes in $\mathbb{A}^2$. When you consider points lying *outside* of the $x$-axis, you aren't considering the $y$-axis, because you're missing the origin. And the point (haha) is that the two distinct axes are the components of the union, but the components are *not* disjoint.

Comment: So strictly speaking it is not true that $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ intersect in the union of $Z_1\cap Z_2 \cap Z_3$ and a line, is it? (This is a statement from Harris' book.)

Comment: Yes it is true, you proved it ! You just didn't need to consider the two cases $X_3\neq  0$ and $X_3=0$. Both of these cases produce points on the line $[0:0:U:V]$. The case $X_3=0$ produces only one point of this line (namely $[0:0:1:0]$) whereas the case $X_3\neq 0$ produces the others.

Answer (score 0):

So...you're right in how you're thinking about this problem. (I actually *just* did this problem last semester in my first alg. geo. class in grad. school and pulled up my solution set.) Ok so you have the line given by $[0:0:1:a]$ union with a point at infinity, $[0:1:0:0]$, a point lying in the set $Z_1\cap Z_2$. Sort of the point here is that you *have* to have both the line *and* the variety $Z_1\cap Z_2\cap Z_3$ in your decomposition of $Z_1\cap Z_2$ and the variety and the line don't have trivial intersection.